# Como deixar campo de busca preparado para pesquisar por qualquer termo

Tags: sql

Tenho um cadastro de texturas onde o código do mesmo é composto por números e em algumas vezes com letras, por exemplo:

```
Código: 2564
Código: C-6551
```

Gostaria de deixar o campo de busca preparado para efetuar a pesquisa por qualquer termo pesquisado pelo usuário, como por exemplo:

Usuário pesquisa pelo código 6551 a busca retornar C-6551, tentei fazer um a busca usando o `REPLACE` mas não deu muito certo, o que fiz foi isso:

```
SELECT *
  FROM cor_textura
 WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(codigo, '.', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') =
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('".$edBusca."', '.', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '')
   AND cor_textura.status = 1
```

Tentei fazer a substituição do termo pesquisa, trocando `ponto` por `espaço`, `traço` por `espaço` e `espaço` por `espaço`.

O banco que estou usando é phpMyAdmin e a estrutura da tabela é essa:

```
`cor_textura` (
  `id_cor_textura` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `img` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cor_textura`)
)
```

Como disse, não consegui resolver o meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você utilizar o comando `LIKE` do qual pesquisa em qualquer parte do texto?

```
SELECT *
  FROM cor_textura
 WHERE codigo like '%6651%'
   AND cor_textura.status = 1
```

Fiz um [exemplo no SQLFindle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eb2e6/1/0), utilizando MySQL, veja se seria isso.

O obteve o retorno:

```
| id | codigo | status |
|----|--------|--------|
|  3 | C-6551 |      1 |
```

Comment: Olá @David, foi um dos teste que fiz e o resultado não ficou correto, não me retornou nada.

Comment: Qual Banco está utilizando? Qual a estrutura da Tabela `cor_textura`, para que eu possa simular.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo no SQLFindle.

Comment: Olá @David, tinha cometido um erro no meu SQL, esqueci de colocar a '$' na variável, valeu pela ajuda.